# Как организовать поиск значения в нескольких ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

Есть 8 ArrayList с разными словами внутри. Есть также переменная типа String в которой записано какое-то слово. Как организовать поиск этого слова сразу во всех Листах? В каждом листе уникальные слова, без повторений

Comment: myList.stream.parallelStream().map( /* реализовываете проверку слов*/)

Comment: А в чем загвоздка? если вы знаете как искать в одном листе нужно просто обойти все листы в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
 private static boolean isContains(List<List<String>> lists, String word) {
    return lists.parallelStream()
                .anyMatch(list -> list.contains(word));
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
System.out.println(isContains(Arrays.asList(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8), "hello"));
```